# Get only Hexadecima values (bytes) from array in ruby

Tags: ruby, byte, chr

I have the following array that represents decimal values of ASCII and non ASCII characters.

```
a=[32, 57, 50, 32, 56, 51, 32, 65, 52, 130, 0, 101, 131, 69, 72, 38, 146, 89, 9]
```

Converting to char looks like this

```
a.map{|b| b.chr}
=> [" ", "9", "2", " ", "8", "3", " ", "A", "4", "\x82", "\x00", "e", "\x83", "E", "H", "&", "\x92", "Y", "\t"]
```

and joining in order to create a string with bytes (pairs of hexadecimal numbers, [0-9A-F]) I do this:

```
a.map{|b| b.chr}.join
=> " 92 83 A4\x82\x00e\x83EH&\x92Y\t"
```

Then I want to remove the string beginning from the first non ASCII value that is \x82 and I do like this but nothing happens.

```
a.map{|b| b.chr}.join.gsub(/\\x.*/,"")
=> " 92 83 A4\x82\x00e\x83EH&\x92Y\t"
```

My expected output is to have only the hexadecimal numbers below:

```
92 83 A4
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

Testing with a larger array like below one, I see that the output is correct only for the @rewritten's solution. The output for this new arrays is **" 92 83 49 26 92 59 00"**

```
a=[32, 57, 50, 32, 56, 51, 32, 52, 57, 32, 50, 54, 32, 57, 50, 32, 53, 57, 
32, 48, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 130, 0, 0, 8, 254, 70, 124, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 3, 
27, 0,2, 27, 3, 0, 227, 7, 1, 14, 17, 33, 0, 28, 14, 47, 38, 146, 89, 9]

a.map(&:chr).join.match(/^( \X\X)+/)[0]            # rewritten's solution
a.map(&:chr).take_while(&"\x80".method(:>)).join   # Aleksei's solution
a.map(&:chr).take_while(&:ascii_only?).join        # cremno's solution

irb(main): a.map(&:chr).join.match(/^( \X\X)+/)[0]
=> " 92 83 49 26 92 59 00"

irb(main): a.map(&:chr).take_while(&"\x80".method(:>)).join
=> " 92 83 49 26 92 59 00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02"

irb(main): a.map(&:chr).take_while(&:ascii_only?).join
=> " 92 83 49 26 92 59 00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02"
```

Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: What will be the output for `a => [" ", "9", "2", " ", "8", "3", " ", "A", "4", "E"]`
Are they always in pair of two ?

Comment: Yes, always in pair of two since represent bytes. The output expectedl should be the same `92 83 A4`

Comment: The thing is that you ask three different things. 1. In the title: "get only hex values"; 2. in the text "get up to first non-ascii"; 3. in the comment above "get all patterns space,hex,hex while matching". alekseimatuskin answered (2), I answered (3), ts answered (1). I think that you should clarify what was the exact question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comment, I assume that you really want to ask about matching pattern "space, hex, hex" up to the first non-match.

This would be like

```
a.map(&:chr).join.match(/^( \X\X)+/)[0]
```

It uses the special `\X` placeholder for regular expressions that matches u̶p̶p̶e̶r̶c̶a̶s̶e̶ hex digits (0-9,A-F,a-f).

---

Additional info:

Again based on my interpretation of the question, if the original array is long (or a stream) there is no need to consume it all. You should better stop generating characters as soon as possible:

```
hexs = "0123456789ABCDEF".split.map(&:ord)
a.
  lazy.
  each_slice(3).
  take_while { |spc, h1, h2| spc == 32 && hexs.include?(h1) && hexs.include?(h2) }.
  flat_map(&:chr).
  to_a.
  join
```

This way any piece of your integer array is not even taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems `\X` catches even lower case hex numbers.

Comment: Indeed. If you want to match only upcase, you have to use a normal range `/^( [A-F0-9]{2})+/`

Comment: Hi rewritten. I tested your code below "Additional info" and I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method join for #<Enumerator::Lazy:0x00000006006ff6c0>`
`

Comment: Please see my update. I changed the accepted answer yours since is the one with correct output. Thanks for the help.

Comment: oh, you need to `.to_a` before the join (just corrected it)

Comment: Thanks. For me your second solution only works a little modified like this `a.each_slice(3).take_while { |spc, h1, h2| spc == 32 && hexs.include?(h1) && hexs.include?(h2) }.flatten.map(&:chr).join
=> " 92 83 49 26 92 59 00"`

Answer (score 3):

Just filter it out *before* joining an array into a string:

```
[" ", "9", "2", " ", "8", "3", " ", "A", "4", "\x82", "\x00"].
  take_while(&"\x80".method(:>))
#⇒ [" ", "9", "2", " ", "8", "3", " ", "A", "4"]
```

Then do whatever you want with the resulting array.

Comment: Why `'y'`? If the OP wants to take up to (excluding) the first non-ascii value, then he needs to compare to `"\x80"`.

Comment: Thanks Aleksei. May you explain please how that works, mainly the part of `&:y.method(:>)`

Comment: `&?y.method(:>)` is just shorthand for `{ |thing| 'y' > thing }`.  Actually two shorthands, as `?y` is `'y'`, and method is dereferenced to a proc. But, as said in previous comment, this does not answer the actual question given in your comment (you should rephrase the question including the case `[" ", "9", "2", " ", "8", "3", " ", "A", "4", "E"]`

Comment: @GerCas your question is answered by the previous comment, just a sidenote: question mark in my previous answer _was not a typo_. There was a question mark and _no_ colon.

Comment: Thanks for help Aleksei. The expression "\x80" means any hexadecimal value or what?

Comment: It’s simply a string, containing one character with ordinal value 128 (80 hex.) The same as `128.chr`.

Comment: `.take_while(&:ascii_only?)`

Comment: @Aleksei Matiushkin Please see my update. I show a larger array and with this one only rewritten's solution works. Thanks anyway for your great help.